# I am using expo , Is there any date picker package for an react native app which should works on both iOS and Android as well

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using expo cli for my react native app. I am looking for a date picker which should work on both iOS and android as well. I tried many packages, But all of them are not working or deprecated. Suggest any package

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try `expo install @react-native-community/datetimepicker`